# How to find $\frac{dz}{dx}$ and $\frac{dz}{dy}$ if $z=\ln(e^x+e^y),$ and $y=x^3$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I have to find $\frac{dz}{dx}$ and $\frac{dz}{dy}$ if $$z=\ln(e^x+e^y), \quad y=x^3.$$
This seems to be a special type of derivative, looks like a compound one - so to find $\frac{dz}{dx}$ I have to keep $y$ constant,right?

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Use: $y=x^3$  =>  $dy=3x^2dx$

You can't use $y$ as constant while diifferentiating w.r.t. $x$ because $y=f(x)=x^3$ and ||ly for $x$

> So,$$dz/dx=\dfrac{e^x+e^y\times dy/dx}{e^x+e^y}$$
>   put $dy/dx=3x^2$
>
> Similarly $$dz/dy=\dfrac{e^x\times dx/dy+e^y}{e^x+e^y}$$
>   put $dx/dy=1/3x^2$